# Finding the Constant to Achieve a Point of Inflection

Tags: derivatives, rational-functions

The function *f(x) = (x+1)^0.5 + **b**/x* needs a point of inflection at x = 3.
I'm looking for a value of **b** that will give me a point of inflection at x=3.
I'm not sure how to do that, could someone help me figure this out?

Comment: Have you found the first and second derivative?

Comment: Do you know what a "point of inflection" [b]is[/b]?  That is a place where the first derivative changes sign which, as long as the function is "nice" happens where the second derivative is 0.  So, as randomgirl1 suggested, you need to find the first and second derivative.  You want the second derivative to be 0 when x= 3.

Comment: @user247327: The *second* derivative changes sign, not the *first*. Also, if the OP doesn't clarify his question I shall vote to close it.

Comment: I found the  second derivative just now, so I will attempt it to equal zero

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few check points in the process:

$f'(x)=\frac{1}{2}(x+1)^\frac{-1}{2}-bx^{-2}$

$f''(x)=\frac{-1}{4}(x+1)^\frac{-3}{2}+2bx^{-3}$

Now you need to solve $f''(3)=0$ for $b$
So your equation should look like:

$f''(3)=0  $

$\frac{-1}{4}(3+1)^{\frac{-3}{2}}+2b(3)^{-3}=0$